# List stays in function memory causing wrong output

Tags: python, list, function

To start, I've solved the problem already, but want to learn more about why it's happening.
Recently I ran into the an issue where I had setup a function which has a list as default value.
Then in the function I appended some values into that list.

Then I ran the function twice and somehow the list remained in memory and the values were appended again.

I had setup a function as below using Python 3.6.8:

```py
def function_a(x = []):
    for item in ["X", "Y", "Z"]:
        x.append(item)
    return x
```

and then I ran it twice and the following occurs:

```py
function_a()
['X', 'Y', 'Z']

function_a()
['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

I tried to find out why it's happening and couldn't find out by googling.
Maybe you can help me out on understanding this =)

Comment: Thank you for the link and marking as duplicate!
I would have never found it otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Mutable default parameters are generally not the best idea.

Your question has already be answered here:
["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)